# How to show related taxonomy terms vith views on term page?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type book and it has a taxonomy term reference field: author. This field can have multiple taxonomy terms.

### What I want to do is to create a views to show related taxonomy terms on taxonomy term page.

For example, if a node has two authors: `term 1` and `term 2` then these terms are "**related**".

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I don't completely understand the question; from where do you want to "draw" this relation - from nodes?

Comment: @AramBoyajyan, yes the relation comes from the nodes.

Comment: So you want to basically scan the nodes the view will show, and then based on that generate the list of related taxonomy terms. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I added some pictures. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: It's clear now; my brain doesn't work anymore, so I'm not really sure if there are any existing solutions/modules you can use. Here's a quick thought: you can create a block in custom module, display it on term pages, fetch view results programmatically, collect the terms of all nodes about to be displayed, and then show them in the block. There are two considerations: 1) I'm not 100% sure if this will work for multi-paged views, so you might need to have another page in view that you'll load in code; 2) turn on views caching; otherwise you'll be running the same query twice. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just an idea: Perhaps you could add a tax term reference field to your terms. Then there might be a way with rules to reference the terms that are referencing the same node. Sorry, I don't have time to solve this.

Comment: Interesting "puzzle", did you ever make any progress on this?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't. :)